# Operating System Not found, while booting

Tags: burg

I installed burg bootloader, as soon as I start my computer it shows "Operating System Not Found", after I press any key on computer it goes to Option Screen without any problem, and from there onwards everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try entering in the terminal of the OS from where you installed burg:

```
sudo update-burg
```

If nothing happens maybe you installed burg in a different OS where grub is installed or the package you installed wasn't updated. Then you can try to just reinstall burg following the instructions from the [Official BURG Page](http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/InstallUbuntu).